# How can we put custom Title in Salesforce1 for Custom VF Tabs?

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, salesforce1-platform

[image]

How can we add a Custom Title in the Salesforce1 header (as shown in my image above)? I want to show "Expenses" title in header as against showing below it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible for now. Because in SF1 vF displayed inside iframe. You can't access outside the `iframe` or can't make any change using jquery, Javascript due to CORS security.

The only option left for you is display the label as currently you are displaing and give background color to give them match.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use SalesForce1 Action Bar.
http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_mobile_salesforce1_newfeat_actionbar_customization.htm

Comment: That wouldnt work for me here. What i need is to display Tab Label in header, action bar is not in context here.

Comment: You would use a custom settings with a free form text and map with respective object and when you render that object's details you will simply use the value from custom settings. If this is complex, you can try using custom labels and you would have a component to get respective value from custom labels and can use that as a action on S1.

Comment: Custom Labels have come hady for me lot of times in such cases for sure.

Comment: Giene please be aware that an answer is a lot more meaningful if you explain the actual answer and put relevant bits into the answer rather then referring to  another website.

Comment: @Giene - My worry is not how I can fetch a label from my app, my issue is how to add Text into Salesforce1 header bar (top blue bar of S1 app, where the Menu and Notification Icons are).